# Referential Constraint from one table to multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

If I have the following tables, is it possible to create a constraint in `#TableNotes` that will check if `InstanceId` exists in `#Users` if `TableId == 1` and checks if `InstanceId` exists in `#Companies` if `TableId == 2`?

```
create table Users(
    UserId int not null,
    TableId int not null default 1
)

create table Companies(
    CompanyId int not null,
    TableId int not null default 2
)

 create table TableNotes(
    InstanceId int not null,
    TableId int not null
 )
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without using triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not designing your table, and instead using two columns to keep the referential integrity correct. I also assume that you mean *TableId* rather than *ModelId*
Something along the following lines would probably would work best for you if you can still change the design of your table.

```
     CREATE TABLE TableNotes(
     TableId int not null,
     UserId int constraint fk_Users_Table_id foreign key references Users(TableId),
     CompanyId int constraint fk_Companies_Table_id foreign key references Companies(TableId)
     )
```

If this is not an option, as you have stated your only option would be to use triggers to keep this in check.